# Assigning song's into database slot, simple music database

Tags: java, database, if-statement

I'm trying to write a method which will look at a datbase(of 4 'slots') find the next empty one and store a song object(artis, name, duration, filesize). Whenever I input data in the program my current method seems to assign the incoming song object to all database 'slots' any help would be great thanks

All 4 java class's are here if anyone could have a look -----> http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=62228

```
public void addSong()
{  
    Song S = new Song();  
    do{  
            if (a.fileSize==0) {

                    setData(a.artist, a.name, a.duration, a.fileSize);
                break;
                } else if (b.fileSize==0) {

                    setData(b.artist, b.name, b.duration, b.fileSize);
                break;
                } else if (c.fileSize==0) {

                    setData(c.artist, c.name, c.duration, c.fileSize);
                break;
                } else if (d.fileSize==0) {

                    setData(c.artist, c.name, c.duration, c.fileSize);
                break;
                }

    }while(true); 
}


public void setData( String artist, String name, double duration, int fileSize)
{
    S.setArtist(artist);
    S.setName(name);
    S.setDuration(duration);
    S.setFileSize(fileSize);
}
```

**EDIT** - 4 database java class's http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=62228

Comment: have you tried removing the do-while loop ?

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing how this code does what you say it should at all. The loop isn't required and to me this appears to be a "loading" method.

Comment: I should have said I added the do-while loop to try and fix the same problem - I though the "break'" statement might fix it - I have no removed the do-while but am still left with the same problem

Comment: I have just added a link to 4 classes if someone could please have a look

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get rid of the loop.

Second, I think your issue is with hiding `S` variable. In `setData` you set `S` properties (here its a global field) when in `addSong` you declare and instantiate a new `S` variable, which you never use.

You can do the following:

1. Make sure you use the correct variable.
2. Pass `S` to `setData` so it will set the fields of a parameter instead of global field.

Comment: Ok, the loops gone, i'm still getting a full database from one song object import. The classes have been pastebinned here;

http://pastebin.com/h8f2T7eg

Comment: Please add all **relevant** code to the question itself. Please add what exactly is wrong.